# .NET Core Razor event after Model Binding for modifications?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-binding

What I'd like to achive is to be able to modiy certain (string) values after they were binded to a property but they are being validated in .NET Core 3.1.

Example poco class:

```
public class MyPoco
{
    [TrimContent]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    
    [TrimContent]
    [MinLength(2)]
    public string? Surname { get; set; }

    [TrimContent]
    [LowerCase]
    public string? EmailAddress { get; set; }
}
```

So let's say a form is posted to the MVC controller and the values entered are
" F " for the first name and " S " as the surname, " My.Email@Address.Com ".
They should be modified, i.e. trimmed to "F" and "S" and the MinLength=2 should be alerted i.e. Also: I can avoid all the `Trim()` statements in my code.

My idea is, that when using a "TrimContentAttribute" (and other attributes that "correct" the values in some way), all values that have been set by previous BindingSourceValueProviders and then are being processed, but before the validation kicks in.

Also attributes marked with LowerCase, should automatically be "ToLower()", so the email address would be "my.email@address.com".

So it the idea would be to declrative approch other than having all the Trim() und ToLowerCase() methods all over the code where the entity is used.

The only idea I came up with so far to write a custom source as described in
[Model Binding in ASP.NET Core - Additional sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#additional-sources-1). But I actually would like to rely on all the default values providers.

Note: There are validators on client side in action as well, but I'd like to have a solution also on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

a new attribute can be created

```
public class MinLengthWithTrim : MinLengthAttribute
{
    public MinLengthWithTrim(int length) : base(length)
    {
    }
    public override bool IsValid(object? value)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        if (str == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return base.IsValid(str.Trim());
    }
}
```

Using:

```
 [MinLengthWithTrim(10)]
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Sure, this would work for the MinLength thing in my example, but is not what I am looking for. My idea is to modify values AFTER they have been binded by a BindingSourceValueProvider / IEnumerableValueProvider.

Maybe another example could be, "LowerCaseAttribute" - i.e. when there is a string EmailAddress property.